# Annotation that replaces another annotation

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

Is it possible to create an annotation that substitutes another?

So I can use:

```
@myConstructor
```

and this is replaced by Lombok annotation:

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
```

I know annotations cannot extends others, but not sure if this substitution is achievable.

Comment: It is done all the time.  See JUnit5 for concrete examples of user defined annotations referencing other annotations.  [section 3.1.1 MetaAnnotations](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations). The catch: the framework needs to support this; it is not automatic.

Comment: In your link I have seen one potential way, that is tagging as meta annotation i.e: `@NoArgs...` and below `public @interface myConstructor {`. However this is not accepted by the framework (it is only intended for Classes). Is there any other way?

Comment: Your question has two questions.  The first question:  Is it possible?  Answer: Yes.  As proof, I gave you JUnit5.  The section I pointed you to has an example where the user created `@Fast` annotation “expands” to `@Tag("fast")`.   The second (implied) (perhaps actual) question: Can you do it with Lombok?  Answer: The framework (Lombok) needs to support it, for it to work.  If it doesn’t work in Lombok today, you can make a request to have support added.  Or, since it is open source, you can add support yourself and submit the changes back to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Lombok does not support this.

You could, however, write your own annotation processor, make sure it runs during compilation *before* the Lombok annotation processor, and let your processor change `@myConstructor` to whatever. Lombok’s processor should then see that. (NB: I did not try that.)